# Как закрепить widget Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

Как сделать так, чтобы `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` оставался постоянно вверху? При таком коде он дублируется через каждую новость:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/feed_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_item_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
            android:textColor="@color/text_dark"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_item_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_medium"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_item_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Это не код, а разметка. Каким образом она используется? Для понимания проблемы недостаточно информации

Comment: Скорее всего вы эту разметку применяете к каждой новости, даже в именах написано ***_item. Попробуйте вынести тулбар в контейнер в котором отображаются все эти итемы

Comment: Эту разметку использую для показа списка новостей. То есть, указывается заголовок, краткий обзор и дата. Вверху хочу разместить Toolbar.

Comment: @СергейТихомиров код покажите как вы его используете

Answer (score 1):

Может так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/feed_item"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
           android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
           android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
           android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_item_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
            android:textColor="@color/text_dark"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_item_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_medium"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_item_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Еще для FrameLayout можно добавить свойство:  android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"